# Raspberry pi 4 is not connecting to WiFi network

Tags: wifi, internet

This is quite a long story but I thought it’d be good to share it all since that might give some perspective and reason to my problem.

I bought a raspberry pi 4 about a year ago to build a “Magic Mirror”. It all started out great and it all worked up until about two weeks ago when there was a power outage. When I restarted the Raspberry Pi and the Magic Mirror software, it asked for an update so I updated it which worked well but when I then ran the MagicMirror software things were out of proportion so I started scaling “modules” down.

Yesterday when I were to run the MagicMirror software again I was greeted by nothing but a black screen. I figured that I would try to re-install the update to see if that would solve the problem but without a WiFi-connection I am unable to update the software.

So now to the actual problem: I have set my home WiFi as the one it’s supposed to auto-connect to but it doesn’t. I then try to “manually” connect to the network so I select the network and enter the password but then nothing happens. I’ve tried to reboot the raspberry pi a couple of times but that doesn’t seem to do any good.

Could anyone please tell me what the problem is and what I should to to solve it? I just want an internet connection man :(

I am very new to this raspberry pi thing so please answer me like I’m a five year old kid (please be very specific on what to do)

Many thanks,
Max

Comment: I would start by trying to connect the Pi to the router via Ethernet cable and do this by downloading a new version of Raspbian Lite to a brand new SD card. Once that works try to see if you can get it to connect to the network via WiFi.  If this works you know you have a working Pi so it’s a software issue.  If not you have a hardware issue.  Then come back and edit the problem.  Without this it’s a bit of a steep climb to say where to start...

Answer (score 1):

"Could anyone please tell me what the problem is and what I should to to solve it?"

Unfortunately NO - you have provided no diagnostic information.
[How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) describes the normal methods of configuring a network, and may help with diagnostics.

You would need to examine the networking config files and run diagnostics like `ip a` etc.

Unfortunately Operating Systems do become corrupt - power failures can cause problems and performing upgrades puts the system under stress, and problems are then more likely.
Experienced users make a backup BEFORE upgrading.

Most of us don't attempt recovery - we just restore from a backup if the image becomes corrupt.